# Error in Importing Image by Pillow library

Tags: python, image, import, python-imaging-library

my code is here to import image in py 2.7

```
from PIL import Image
fimg=Image.open('C:/Users/Haseeb/esktop/Images/billa_jpg_000.jpg')
```

But i am getting this of error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Python for Begginers\newcode.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 115, in <module>
    import numbers
  File "c:\Python27\Python for Begginers\numbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import image
ImportError: cannot import name image
```

Answer (score -1):

Pillow is trying to import the "numbers" module.

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py#L116

https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html

But you have a file called numbers.py which it is trying to open instead. If you rename it, it should work.

Comment: It also looks like you have a typo in the image path, esktop not Desktop.

Comment: Dear Hugo i tried to rename it but still the image cant be import as the following error throws.

from PIL import image
pil_im=Image.open('C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\Images\lingo.jpg')

Comment: The error's not shown in your comment. Please edit your question and add it there.